# How do I access the ref portion of a URL in rails before redirect?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, url, referrer

I had some code that was working that now seems to be broken, and I'm trying to hunt down why. It seems the issue focuses partially around my referral system.

Once a user signs up, they are given a unique referral code i.e. http://localhost:3000/?ref=b9270b78a6 (from my local machine). They can, in theory, then pass this on to their friends, and when their friends come to the site via their referral URL, I log the ref and credit the initial user with +1 referral.

While it was working, the URL came in, the program issues a GET command for "/?ref=b9270b78a6" and was redirected to '/frontpage' but the ref was stored as params[:ref]. Now params[:ref] is blank, and it's basically making my program say that no one referred anyone else.

It seems that I've deleted something important unintentionally, but I don't know what.

My problem is that a) I don't know how to capture the 'b9270b78a6' as prams[:ref], and on top of that it seems that I'm losing my chance to do that as the redirect points the browser to a generic URL and executes the 'StaticPagesController#frontpage' controller action before I could grab the code anyways:

```
Started GET "/?ref=b9270b78a6" for ::1 at 2015-10-20 16:19:36 -0400
Started GET "/frontpage" for ::1 at 2015-10-20 16:19:36 -0400
Processing by StaticPagesController#frontpage as HTML
```

In short: any idea on how I grab the ref code and saving it as params[:ref]?

I don't even know what code (controller, model, view) you might need to see to get to the bottom of this, so happy to update with whatever might be useful. My closest stab in the dark is that I'll need to use URI::parse(url) to then parse the incoming URL, but again - by the time I could potentially do that it's been redirected and I cannot.

Any thoughts are much appreciated!

Comment: I don't see a redirect message in the logs.  Redirections in routes will do this.

Comment: What do you mean by `saving it as params[:ref]`? Do you always want it to appear there?

Comment: @Swards ...I guess that's a good point. In my frantic rush to fix this I hadn't considered that. Any thoughts on what that might mean? It's like there's an existing route defined that's sending it from the ?ref= b9270b78a6 to /frontpage. But after looking through (to be safe), I don't see anything!

Comment: I'd look into the middleware, something is happening before you get to the controller.  Any controller redirects will show in the logs.  What other gems have you added that may affect access?

Comment: @BroiSatse well, that's how I'm accessing it in my other methods. I assign a user a referral code upon signup, the code is then used by other users and when the inbound URL has a code in it I check (using params[:ref]...I suppose it could be anything) the users to find the person who referred them.

Comment: @Swards I checked my gemlist and it looks like I have Devise. Though to be brutally honest, I don't know why it's there or what it does. I assumed it was a dependency since I don't have it in my gemfile

Comment: Devise is there for user authentication.  Not exactly sure of when devise looks for the user_id in the session, but it may be before the controller.  Do you have a before action in the controller? `:authenticate_user!` may do this.

Comment: @Swards Huh...that's odd. Given the minimalist app, I do not actually use any authentication. I do have a callback at the beginning of the controller. Presumably removing it would solve the issue?

Comment: You can try removing gems to see if one of them is doing it.  Try Devise first.

Comment: @Swards Welp, it was my routes. What the heck...I haven't changed those in 8 weeks, and they break suddenly. Not to mention it was the most innocuous little route. Absolutely no reason this should have happened, but Happy Rails, it did. Thanks for all the input. I actually learned a fair amount about Devise in the process :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

False alarm everyeone...it was my routes. What the heck...I haven't changed those in 8 weeks, and they break suddenly. Not to mention it was the most innocuous little route. Absolutely no reason this should have happened, but Happy Rails, it did.

Thanks to @Swards for your help, and for the learning experience!

Answer (score 2):

Glad you found the cause.  Some of those errors are very hard to find with the usual debugging methods.

Btw - another tip.  Throw the ref in a session - you can do this with a before action in the application controller and then the ref value will be available when you need it.

```
# application_controller.rb
before_action :set_ref

def set_ref
  session[:ref] ||= params[:ref] if params[:ref]
end
```

Then later you can get it when you save

```
referring_user_id = session[:ref]
```

Comment: Thanks! I've seen that method after additional looking around, and have implemented it, now that I know I can and what my actual problem is. Thanks again!